# Height of footer too low

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I increase the size of a footer and make the font size bigger ? Do I need to use custom css ?

Here is my footer -

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: CSS, width and height. Try Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some custom CSS, but it's not a lot and it's quite easy to do:

```
​.ui-page .ui-footer .ui-btn-text {
    font-size : 20px;
}​
```

That will change the `font-size` of the button text in your footer. `.ui-page` refers to all of the `data-role="page"` elements, `.ui-footer` refers to the footer within each page, and `.ui-btn-text` refers to the `span` element inside the navigation buttons that holds each button's text.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qXVhv/

You can change the `height` of the navigation bar by changing the `height` of the link elements:

```
.ui-page .ui-footer .ui-navbar a {
    height : 100px;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qXVhv/1/